# Chrome suggests some domains with a lower dash

Tags: google-chrome

I have a "problem" throughout several Chrome versions already.

[image]

Those errornous domains can be removed, but they will come back a few days / weeks / months later. I am syncing with Chrome for Android and several other computers using the same account. All computers share the same set of addons.

uBlock is probably the only one interacting with all sites, since the problem exists for several domains.